# Bootcamp partition still remains after removing Windows

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I installed Windows on my MacBook some time ago, and during that it created two partitions called Bootcamp. (So I had the Mac partition, a Bootcamp partition and another Bootcamp partition) I tried uninstalling Windows thinking that both partitions would be removed, but after using Bootcamp Assistant, Windows was successfully uninstalled, but the extra Bootcamp partition still remained. I tried using Disk Utility to restore that partition back into MacOS, but it just threw up an error saying "Unable to restore partition". No details were given as to why.

Comment: What error did you receive?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Submitting a comment to that answer is one way